# How do I add a cover image to an iBook that lacks one?

Tags: itunes, books

I have several iBooks, purchased from the iBooks store that either never had cover images (typically because they are inexpensive "generics") or have "lost" them on iOS (for reasons that aren't clear; but some, at least, are no longer available in the store), though they have covers in iBooks on OS X. It was once possible to add covers in iTunes, but this is no longer comparable with syncing purchases through the cloud.

How do I add a cover image to an iBook that lacks one?

Comment: Just to be clear: turning on "Sync Books" (if that indeed still works) is [*not* a viable option](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/143953/4395).

Comment: You can do this sort of thing in Calibre but it's a PITA. iTunes is a beast and should be broken up... so they hive off the books bit... the new stuff looks pretty but lacks functionality... a few versions later it catches up. We all just need loads of patience!